# USB Powered modes

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, usb, usb-device, usb-c

I was trying to understand USB and Ethernet interfaces and found this device and its associated hardware design checklist - [Link](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/LAN7800-HW-Design-Checklist-00003446.pdf).

On page 10, Section 9-2 of the hardware design checklist, they have a section called VBUS_DET.

Can someone tell me how to understand this section? How to understand the three modes, and why it's there in the first place?

Should the same modes be followed when the device is connected to a connector or a USB Hub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me how to understand this section? How to understand the 3 modes and why its there in the first place?

The chip is designed for general USB applications and for the sake of functionality,  the chip allows the designer to select the operation mode. VBUS_DET function is used to put the device in powered or unpowered modes and required when to reset the chip.

1. Self Power Mode: Useful for downstream devices. Use this config if you want to keep the chip reset when not connected to a USB upstream port. OTG is a good example to this.
2. Permanently Attached Mode: Useful when you don't need any VBUS detection reset or reconfiguration.
3. Bus Powered Mode: This is what basically an upstream port is. If you are designing a computer this mode is needed for USB ports.

---

Here's a real world example: In a single board computer (SBC) I designed recently, I put two USB type A for upstream and one micro USB for OTG:

- Upstream ports were in **bus powered mode** because they were there to accept downstream devices such as mice, keyboards, memory sticks, flash drives etc. i.e. the ports provide 5V to the external devices and don't need any VBUS detection reset.
- OTG was in **self power mode** because that port was supposed to be in sleep mode until the device is connected to a computer. When it's connected to computer, the port detects voltage from external world and then wakes up and resets itself.

I also put an Ethernet-to-USB bridge for a 2nd ethernet port functionality to the SBC. The bridge was on the same board and connected to the processor through USB. It was in **permanently attached mode** because it wouldn't be detached during normal operation.